# Could not find or load main class "Name of class" in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javac

When I use the java/javac command on cmd as in

`javac Theory/HelloWorld.java`
`java Theory.HelloWorld`

it works just fine, yet when I do that on the VSCode terminal it doesn't work at all and says "Error: Could not find or load main class Theory.HelloWorld. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Theory.HelloWorld"

Running the code with the Run Java button works just fine, it's just when I want to add arguments
Any ideas?

PS: Using the java -cp . Theory/HelloWorld works fine, it's just that it becomes a mess when I try to use that command when the main class uses different classes

I've tried `set CLASSPATH=.`
Clean Java Language Server Workspace
Used different terminals
Configured Classpath in VSCode with the "." path

Comment: *it's just that it becomes a mess when I try to use that command when the main class uses different classes* How so? Please give an example.

Comment: "it becomes a mess when I try to use that command when the main class uses different classes", why? You don't need to put every class on the classpath, just the root directory or jar(s) or some such.

Comment: When the main class is using different classes in the same package, if I want to run the command javac [location].java it says that it cannot find symbol [Class name]

Comment: Just try `javac -cp . Theory/*.java`

Comment: is the cwd the same in both cases you are comparing?

Comment: Should be related to your working directory. Can you show your workspace and project structure?

Comment: Any updates here?